# Windows form closing automatically when parent window gets focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

VB Windows form Application.. I am developing an application of which part of the program is around configuration settings allowing the user to enter configuration items. When the menubar item for configuration menu is clicked on the main form the menu opens. This is fine but the mainform should not become active again until the configuration menu has closed. This does not happen right now and the mainform simply comes to the foreground and the configuration form goes to the background... I realize that coding an event on the Child form to handle this would not work because the child window loses control and the main form gains control.. I thought of coding a function as follows on the main form but it does not seem logical because i would have to add to it for everyform and do checking to make sure the child is actually open before trying to close it..

```
 Private Sub Form1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
    MailSettingsWindow.Close()
    RentalSettingsWindow.Close()

End Sub
```

I did away with the above sub routine and used the below code as per the recomendation of using showdialog which works just as i was looking for.

```
   Private Sub MailingAndEmailSettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MailingAndEmailSettingsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim MailConfig As New MailSettingsWindow()
    MailSettingsWindow.Showdialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: Changing the focus should be a **non-destructive** action. Remember, Windows is a multi-tasking operating system, and the user will expect to be able to multi-task. If your application works *differently*, they'll be confused, disoriented, and probably blame you, even if your pattern is "better" or "innovative". Users should be able to set focus to another window in your app without losing information or things on the screen randomly closing. Don't close windows unless they specifically *close* a window.

Comment: Understandable.. But if the user enters a configuration window for the application they should not be able to leave that window open and still be able to use the Application until they have either made changes and saved them or simply clicked the close button or cancel button.

Comment: so, you've to block the parent form, until the settings' window is close??

Comment: So you're looking for a modal dialog? They have to OK or cancel the configuration dialog before interacting with the main window? That's the typical pattern in a Windows application. Use the `ShowDialog` method to display it, rather than `Show`.

Comment: And you can use IF MailSettingsWindow.Show() = OK then // If MailSettingsWindow.Show() = Cancel Then // To take control of what the user have clicked on his way out. (Remeber to set a OKButton and a CancelButton, to use this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did away with the above sub routine and used the below code as per the recommendation of using [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) which works just as I was looking for.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub MailingAndEmailSettingsMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MailingAndEmailSettingsMenuItem.Click
    Dim MailConfig As New MailSettingsWindow()
    MailSettingsWindow.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```